# event deprecated in typescript 3.5.3

Tags: typescript

In Typescript version 3.5.3 I found that event is now marked as deprecated. 
this can be found in file lib.dom.d.ts.
I didn't found any reference in JS documents that this is indeed deprecated.

Can anyone please explain this ?

```
/** @deprecated */
declare var event: Event | undefined;
```

Comment: there is some info why you should avoid it - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event